# Bash script to create directories and files with a numbered prefix

Tags: bash

I wrote a pretty simple bash script. It takes a directory with subdirectories with incremental prefixes in their names (`01test, 02test, 03test`), creates a new directory with the next highest prefix and creates a couple of files and fills them with some default text.

I'd like to do this in fewer lines of code and eliminate redundancies.

```
#!/bin/bash

LAST=`exec ls example_dir | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g' | sort -n | tail -1`
PREFIX="${LAST:0:2}"
PREFIX=$((PREFIX + 1))
PREFIX="$PREFIX"_
ARGS=$@
TESTNAME="${ARGS// /_}"
DIRNAME="example_dir/$PREFIX$TESTNAME"

mkdir $DIRNAME
mkdir $DIRNAME/some_directory
mkdir $DIRNAME/expected

touch $DIRNAME/first.txt
touch $DIRNAME/second.txt
touch $DIRNAME/third.json

echo "{" >> $DIRNAME/test.json
echo -e "\t\"enabled\": true" >> $DIRNAME/test.json
echo "}" >> $DIRNAME/test.json

echo "{" >> $DIRNAME/some_directory/$PREFIX.json
echo -e "  \"entities\": [" >> $DIRNAME/some_directory/$PREFIX.json
echo "  ]" >> $DIRNAME/some_directory/$PREFIX.json
echo "}" >> $DIRNAME/some_directory/$PREFIX.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `tail` must to read the whole file. Calling `sort` with a `-r` (aka `--reverse` option) you can use `head` instead.
- `touch` takes multiple arguments. You may

  ```
  touch $DIRNAME/first.txt $DIRNAME/second.txt $DIRNAME/third.json
  ```

  and further use brace expansion:

  ```
  touch $DIRNAME/{first.txt,second.txt,third.json}
  ```
- I would consider here-documenting the json files instead of echoing them, along the lines of:

  ```
  cat << EOF >> $DIRNAME/test.json
  {
       "enabled": true
  }
  EOF
  ```

Comment: isn't there a `<` missing? I think it has to look like: `cat << EOF >> $DIRNAME/test.json`